# Have you had problems with Dojo 1.7.1 in Internet Explorer 7/8?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, dojo

I have been working on upgrading an application from dojo 1.4.3 to 1.7.1. Everything is working great in Firefox/Chrome/Safari, but IE7 and IE8 are both failing. The first failure appears to be coming from the code in dojo/ready around line 40.

```
    try{
        f();
    }
    // FIXME: signal the error via require.on
    finally{
        onLoadRecursiveGuard = 0;
    }
```

Has anyone else noticed problems with this? Is there a work around? Dojo claims it should work in IE 6 - 9, but I have seen other comments that suggest the try/finally will break in IE without the catch. Is this true? Thanks for any insight into this problem ahead of time!

Comment: can you provide a test case which fails?

Comment: I resolved this issue. The problem was that the code was failing when there was an error thrown within the try. Because there was no catch, the IE console was showing the error originate here. The problem with IE I was having was that methods such as getChildren() were returning a standard array, instead of a NodeList, which I believe was returned in previous versions. In many places throughout the code, we were running getChildren().forEach, etc. which was causing the issue. Switching these to dojo.forEach fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem and it was because safeMixin was called throughout my code without checking the arguments passed in.  safeMixin is 'supposed' to have a valid object passed in as an argument.

This can happen up if you 'new' an object with an empty constructor and then pass the args directly into safeMixin.  There are other cases as well.

[Here is a bug report.](http://bugs.dojotoolkit.org/ticket/14275)

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem when using JsonRest:

```
var jr = new JsonRest(); // cause exception
var jr = new JsonRest({}); // it works
```